# How to get Task created by asyncio.start_server that runs client_connected_cb

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Here are the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html

`asyncio.start_server` takes in a `client_connected_cb`, which is run in a `Task` as soon as a client connects to the server. My goal is to write a `teardown` function that waits until everything is finished: all readers are done, all writers are done, and all tasks created by the server are done. In order to do that, I need to know the `Task`s created by the server that are running the `client_connected_cb`, but I cannot figure out how to do that?

Is there some way to get this `Task`? Otherwise I have to resort to hacks where every time `client_connected_cb` is created, I store it in a dictionary of some sort and then wait for that dictionary to be cleared by polling it or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fine grained control you could create a custom `task_factory` to catch all new tasks and do something with them, like adding a callback to all new tasks of a type that you want to do something after it finishes.
`Task.add_done_callback(callback)`

```
def end(task: asyncio.Task):
    print(f'Task: {task.get_name()} Finished')
tasks = []
def my_task_factory(loop, coro):
    task = asyncio.Task(coro, loop=loop)
    if task.get_coro().__name__ == 'handle_client':
        task.add_done_callback(end)
    tasks.append(task)
    return task  # type: asyncio.Task

Loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Loop.set_task_factory(my_task_factory)
```

---

There is also 2 high level methods for accessing tasks.
[current_task()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.current_task) [all_tasks()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.all_tasks)
`asyncio.current_task(loop=None)` # Returns _asyncio.Task
`asyncio.all_tasks(loop=None)`  # Returns a set of _asyncio.Task

```
import _asyncio
import asyncio
from asyncio import StreamReader, StreamWriter
class Server:
    def __init__(self,  bind_ip='localhost', bind_port=15555):
        self.Loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.bind_port = bind_port
        self.bind_ip = bind_ip

    def startup(self):
        self.Server_Task = self.Loop.create_task(self._run_server(), name='Server')
        self.Loop.run_forever()

    async def _run_server(self):
        self.Server = await asyncio.start_server(self.handle_client, host=self.bind_ip, port=self.bind_port)
        async with self.Server:
            print(f'Listening on {self.bind_ip}:{self.bind_port}')
            await self.Server.serve_forever()

    async def handle_client(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
        peer = writer.get_extra_info('peername')  # type: Tuple[str, int]
        try:
            task = asyncio.current_task(self.Loop) # type: _asyncio.Task
            tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(self.Loop) # type: Set # of _asyncio.Task
            print(f'Tasks Type:{type(tasks)}\n------')
            for i in tasks:
                print(f'Task: Type:{type(i)}\nTask: {i.get_name()}\nCoro: {i.get_coro().__name__}')
            print(f'------\nhandle_client: Type:{type(task)}\nTask: {task.get_name()}\nCoro: {task.get_coro().__name__}')
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

        finally:
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            print(f'Closed: {peer}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TCPServer = Server()
    TCPServer.startup()
    print('End')
```

[image: output]